# iptables setup for bridge, redirect dns traffic

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, bridge

I am trying to forward dns traffic on a bridge to a local dns server and it wasn't working. As a thought exercise I decided to block all traffic and that too isn't working. Here is my setup :

```
#/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual

#allow-hotplug br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

results for `sudo iptables -L` (The MAC addresses are for eth0 and eth1):

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MAC 10:6A:FD:32:07:7F
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MAC B7:23:EC:30:BE:B7

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere      

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

results for `ifconfig` :

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:6A:FD:32:07:7F 
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2602:30a:c038:f980::3ec/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::129a:ddff:fe41:907d/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2602:30a:c038:f980:6806:dd7b:14eb:a2b0/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:83 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:39900 (38.9 KiB)  TX bytes:11753 (11.4 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B7:23:EC:30:BE:B7
          inet addr:169.254.199.229  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53413 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52083764 (49.6 MiB)  TX bytes:12746138 (12.1 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:6A:FD:32:07:7F 
          inet addr:169.254.166.137  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:52904 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:11527039 (10.9 MiB)  TX bytes:53215987 (50.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14428 (14.0 KiB)  TX bytes:14428 (14.0 KiB)
```

This is only part I wasn't sure about `eth0` and `eth1` recieved random ip addresses.

Connection setup :

`Router -> (eth0)Server(eth1) -> Switch -> devices`

The Server is where I am trying to drop all packets. But devices connected to eth1 and are able to send and receive all traffic. My actual goal is forward all DNS traffic to a local DNS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traffic going over a bridge doesn't (necessarily) go through netfilter.  Check the value of the `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` sysctl; if it's `0`, then that's the problem -- set it to `1` and all will be well again.

On kernel 3.18 or later, you may need to load the `br_netfilter` module in order to make the above sysctl available.

Comment: I get the error `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables: No such file or directory` I am running debian

Comment: I fixed this with `modprobe br_netfilter` for some reason the bridge module wasn't being loaded.

Comment: Wow, that's a new one on me.  Huh, look at that, [br_netfilter got pulled out into a module in 3.18 "for performance reasons"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/34666d467cbf1e2e3c7bb15a63eccfb582cdd71f).  Learn something new every day.

Comment: yeah took me a while to track down. Do you have any suggestions on how to do what I originally wanted ? forward all DNS requests coming from devices connected to eth1 to the server itself ?

Comment: @John a simple `REDIRECT` rule should do the trick.  Probably best to ask a new question if you need more detailed guidance.

Comment: thanks for your help. I setup a new question here if you can help further : http://serverfault.com/questions/720222/iptables-to-redirect-dns-queries-on-bridge